# How to alter text filters conditionally based on content type?

Tags: input-formats

How can I get the content type of the current node from within a text filter, so I can use it to conditionally alter how the filter is applied?

Getting the node ID from the `arg()` function and using it to load a node object does not work because the text filter is run multiple (30+) times and exhausts the available memory.

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if ( !empty($node) ) {
  dd('Have a node, do something');
}
```

The same is true with the following method of getting the content type: `$node = menu_get_object();`

Comment: So basically the question would be: What the most lightweight way to load a node's "type" property from the URL. Right? Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You could go with the following code inside your filter's callback function:

```
if(arg(0) == 'node' && arg(1) > 0){
  $result = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('type'))
  ->condition('nid', arg(1),'=')
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAssoc();
  dsm($result['type']);
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
check this  replace $user with node  condition node_type = "YOUR_NODE_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME"; // can find this on the node type's "edit" screen in the Drupal admin section.

$result = db_query("SELECT nid FROM node WHERE type = :nodeType ", array(':nodeType'=>$node_type));

$nids = array();

    function hide_formats_permission() {
      return array(
        'show text format dropdown' => array(
          'title' => t('Show text format dropdown'),
          'description' => t('Show the text format dropdowns where more than one text format is available. If a user does not have this permission then the text format dropdown will be displayed in a collapsed fieldset.'),
        ),
      );
    }

    /**
     * Implements hook_element_info_alter().
     *
     * We are using the implementation of better_formats module to intercept the display of input formats and
     * display this with our own function
     *
     */
    function hide_formats_element_info_alter(&$type) {
      // Change text format processing on elements to our version.
      if (isset($type['text_format']['#process'])) {
        foreach ($type['text_format']['#process'] as &$callback) {
          if ($callback === 'filter_process_format') {
          $callback = 'hide_formats_filter_process_format';
          }
        }
      }
    }

    /*
     * Started as a direct copy of filter_process_format from core filter.module
     */
    function hide_formats_filter_process_format($element) {
      global $user;

      // Ensure that children appear as subkeys of this element.
      $element['#tree'] = TRUE;
      $blacklist = array(
        // Make form_builder() regenerate child properties.
        '#parents',
        '#id',
        '#name',
        // Do not copy this #process function to prevent form_builder() from
        // recursing infinitely.
        '#process',
        // Description is handled by theme_text_format_wrapper().
        '#description',
        // Ensure proper ordering of children.
        '#weight',
        // Properties already processed for the parent element.
        '#prefix',
        '#suffix',
        '#attached',
        '#processed',
        '#theme_wrappers',
      );
      // Move this element into sub-element 'value'.
      unset($element['value']);
      foreach (element_properties($element) as $key) {
        if (!in_array($key, $blacklist)) {
          $element['value'][$key] = $element[$key];
        }
      }

      $element['value']['#type'] = $element['#base_type'];
      $element['value'] += element_info($element['#base_type']);

      // Turn original element into a text format wrapper.
      $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'filter');
      $element['#attached']['js'][] = $path . '/filter.js';
      $element['#attached']['css'][] = $path . '/filter.css';

      // Setup child container for the text format widget.
      $element['format'] = array(
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('filter-wrapper')),
      );

      /*
       * Add custom display.
       */
      if (user_access('show text format dropdown')) {
        $element['format']['#title'] = "Text formats options";  // Title is needed in our theme or you can't expand the fieldset
        $element['format']['#collapsible'] = TRUE;
        $element['format']['#collapsed'] = TRUE;

        // Add custom CSS to fix overlap in fieldsets for seven theme. #17892227
        global $theme;
        if ($theme == 'seven') {
          $custom_css = 'fieldset.filter-wrapper { padding-bottom: 20px;} fieldset.filter-wrapper div.fieldset-wrapper { padding-top: 20px;}';
          drupal_add_css($custom_css, 'inline');
        }
      }

      // Prepare text format guidelines.
      $element['format']['guidelines'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('filter-guidelines')),
        '#weight' => 20,
      );
      // Get a list of formats that the current user has access to.
      $formats = filter_formats($user);
      foreach ($formats as $format) {
        $options[$format->format] = $format->name;
        $element['format']['guidelines'][$format->format] = array(
          '#theme' => 'filter_guidelines',
          '#format' => $format,
        );
      }

      // Use the default format for this user if none was selected.
      if (!isset($element['#format'])) {
        $element['#format'] = filter_default_format($user);
      }

      $element['format']['format'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Text format'),
        '#options' => $options,
        '#default_value' => $element['#format'],
        '#access' => count($formats) > 1,
        '#weight' => 10,
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('filter-list')),
        '#parents' => array_merge($element['#parents'], array('format')),
      );

      $element['format']['help'] = array(
        '#type' => 'container',
        '#theme' => 'filter_tips_more_info',
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('filter-help')),
        '#weight' => 0,
      );

      $all_formats = filter_formats();
      $format_exists = isset($all_formats[$element['#format']]);
      $user_has_access = isset($formats[$element['#format']]);
      $user_is_admin = user_access('administer filters');

      // If the stored format does not exist, administrators have to assign a new
      // format.
      if (!$format_exists && $user_is_admin) {
        $element['format']['format']['#required'] = TRUE;
        $element['format']['format']['#default_value'] = NULL;
        // Force access to the format selector (it may have been denied above if
        // the user only has access to a single format).
        $element['format']['format']['#access'] = TRUE;
      }
      // Disable this widget, if the fieldset .fieldset-wrapperuser is not allowed to use the stored format,
      // or if the stored format does not exist. The 'administer filters' permission
      // only grants access to the filter administration, not to all formats.
      elseif (!$user_has_access || !$format_exists) {
        // Overload default values into #value to make them unalterable.
        $element['value']['#value'] = $element['value']['#default_value'];
        $element['format']['format']['#value'] = $element['format']['format']['#default_value'];

        // Prepend #pre_render callback to replace field value with user notice
        // prior to rendering.
        $element['value'] += array('#pre_render' => array());
        array_unshift($element['value']['#pre_render'], 'filter_form_access_denied');

        // Cosmetic adjustments.
        if (isset($element['value']['#rows'])) {
          $element['value']['#rows'] = 3;
        }
        $element['value']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
        $element['value']['#resizable'] = FALSE;

        // Hide the text format selector and any other child element (such as text
        // field's summary).
        foreach (element_children($element) as $key) {
          if ($key != 'value') {
            $element[$key]['#access'] = FALSE;
          }
        }
      }

      return $element;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is just calling the same function over and over, you could use the following code.

```
  // Use the advanced drupal_static() pattern, since this is called very often.
  static $drupal_static_fast;
  if (!isset($drupal_static_fast)) {
    $drupal_static_fast['node'] = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__);
  }
  $node = &$drupal_static_fast['node'];
  if (empty($node)) {
    // The function was not called earlier.
    $node = menu_get_object();
    // …
  }
```

Generally speaking, an input filter should never try to understand in which context it is being called, if not from the given parameters. In fact, an input filter could be called:

- In a page listing different nodes, which is what happens for the front page, for example
- For each of the comments for a node, which could be show in the same page together the node itself
- In every context a module calls [`check_markup()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/check_markup/7.x)